# zend findManyToManyRowset subselect group by

Tags: zend-framework, group-by, subquery

I need to find findManyToManyRowset with order by and group by selects for intersection table.

SQL for intersection sub select looks like:

```
$order = "select *
from intersection
order by someCol desc";

$group = "select order.*
from ($order) as order
group by order.otherCol";
```

result sub select string is $group.

5th parameter $select of findManyToManyRowset should be Zend_Db_Table_Select, but I'm stuck at this poin, becouse I can't do true sub select with Zend_Db_Table_Select and becouse in findManyToManyRowset(..)
there is strings

```
if ($select === null) {
    $select = $matchTable->select();
} else {
    $select->setTable($matchTable);
}

    $select->from(array('i' => $interName), array(), $interSchema)
           ->joinInner(array('m' `enter code here`=> $matchName), $joinCond, Zend_Db_Select::SQL_WILDCARD, $matchSchema)
           ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

and they are breaking all I do in $select ($group)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

I'v change SQL string [this way](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

to

```
select
*
from someTable st1
where groupCol =
    (
    select
        max(st2.groupCol)
    from someTable st2
    where
        st1.firstId=st2.firstId
        and st1.secondId=st2.secondId
        ....
        and etc
    )
--and groupResult=1;
```

so I have same result without subselect of order by and without join's.

Zend code:

```
    $matchTable,$intersectionTable - should be instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract with correct reference map

        $max = $intersectionTable->select()
                ->from(array('mx' => 'intersectionTableName'), new Zend_Db_Expr("max(mx.groupCol)"))
                ->where('i.firstId = mx.firstId')
                ->where('i.secondId = mx.secondId')
                ...
                -> etc ;


        $select = $matchTable->select()
//                  ->where('i.groupResult = ?', true) optional, in case we would like to filter result rowset by grouped value
                    ->where('i.groupCol = ?', $max);



        $result = $row->findManyToManyRowset($matchTable, $intersectionTable, null, null, $select);
```